# How to get multiple values from AttributeValue Map in java dynamodb query?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I want to get all items from a dynamo db table. i have written a query in java as below and it works. but the problem is that it doesn't add all the columns to the AttributeValue Map. it has only the first column (key). so what i do here is searching every item by key in the loop. so it is not efficient if your table has millions of data as i search every item in the loop. what can i do to avoid this situation ? 
note: 'name' is the first column in the table. (primary key)

i tried to get the 'count' as i did like 'name' but it doesn't return anything for 'count' but null.

```
    Table table = dynamoDb.getTable(DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME);

    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest(DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME);
    ArrayList<DeviceResponse>deviceResponses=new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, AttributeValue> exclusiveStartKey = null;
    do {
        final ScanResult scanResult = client.scan(scanRequest);
        List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> items = scanResult.getItems();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            Map<String, AttributeValue> map = items.get(i);

            AttributeValue value = map.get("name");
            String name = value.getS();

            Item item = table.getItem("name", name); //Searching item
            int count = item.getInt("count"); //getting count from item

            DeviceResponse deviceResponse = new DeviceResponse();
            deviceResponse.setName(name);
            deviceResponse.setCount(count);

            deviceResponses.add(deviceResponse);
        }

        exclusiveStartKey = scanResult.getLastEvaluatedKey();

        // Reusing same request object, just setting the start key
        scanRequest.setExclusiveStartKey(exclusiveStartKey);
    } while(exclusiveStartKey != null);

    return deviceResponses;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i tried to get the 'count' as i did like 'name'

No you didn't. This code where you get `name`:

```
AttributeValue value = map.get("name");
String name = value.getS();
```

Is not equivalent to this code where you attempt to get `count`:

```
Item item = table.getItem("name", name); //Searching item
int count = item.getInt("count"); //getting count from item
```

You are taking the `name` field, and then executing another query against the database for some reason. All the attributes are in the `Map<String, AttributeValue> map` object. If you wanted to get an attribute named `count` the same way you got the attribute named `name` then the code would be the following:

```
AttributeValue value = map.get("count");
int count = value.getN();
```

Or just simplify it like so:

```
int count = map.get("count").getN();
```